# How to install Linux packages in Replit

Tags: linux, bash, replit

I tried to use `nasm` in a `bash` project on Replit (educator) but it failed as `nasm` was not installed. 
However, there are some assembly projects on Replit. So I forked a project, added my code, and boom it worked. 
How `nasm` got installed in that project? Dunno, cause it's nowhere explained.

Now, I'd like to use external functions like `printf` in the assembly code. The code being `x86-32`, I need to install something similar to `glibc-devel.i686` and  `glibc-devel` (this on Fedora). Seems to be `gcc-multilib` in Ubuntu.

My question is : how do we install Linux packages in a `bash` project on Replit? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `install-pkg` doesn't seem to work. I'm looking at Nix now, but I'm not sure I understand everything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a Linux package in a `bash` project on Replit, run the command **directly from the console or shell**. If the command is found on Nix, you'll get an invite to run it from Nix and the package will be added to the config file `replit.nix` in your poject.

```bash
> nasm --version
nasm: command not installed, but was located via Nix.
Would you like to run nasm from Nix and add it to your replit.nix file? [Yn]:
```

```bash
> cat replit.nix
{ pkgs }: {
    deps = [
        pkgs.nasm
        pkgs.bashInteractive
    ];
}
```

However, if the command you're trying to run is in a script, pressing the **"Run"** button or launching the script from the shell will only give an error "`Command not found`".

You can also add the package to your project by directly editing `replit.nix`.

You can check if your package exists in Nix using the [NixOS Search - Packages](https://search.nixos.org/packages) page.

Comment: BTW, you're not stuck with the version of nixpkgs that the replit folks have precached; you can pull in other flakes, alternate nixpkgs versions (for software releases that NixOS no longer ships), etc.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks for adding this precision.

Answer (score 0):

In bash type:

```bash
$ nix-env -iA nixpkgs.nasm
```